# Error using categorical column in geom_density

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-ggplot

When converting a column to a type categorical, and setting the some aesthetics property (aes()) to use it, I'm getting the following error:

`NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex`

For example, here's a reproducible example:

```
randCat = np.random.randint(0,2,500)
randProj = np.random.rand(1,500)
df = pd.DataFrame({'proj': np.ravel(randProj),'cat': np.ravel(randCat)})
df['cat'] = df['cat'].map({0:'firstCat', 1:'secondCat'}) 


df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype('category')
g = ggplot(aes(x='proj', color='cat',fill='cat'), data=df) + geom_density(alpha=0.7)
print(g)
```

I'm using `pandas version 0.22.0`.
And `ggplot 0.11.5`

Interestingly enough, the plot comes out fine when I'm not setting the "cond" column to be a "categorical" type (remains as string). However, for different purposes I need this column to categorical.

A more complete trace of the error:

```
     54     # hack (for now) because MI registers as ndarray
     55     elif isinstance(obj, ABCMultiIndex):
---> 56         raise NotImplementedError("isna is not defined for MultiIndex")
     57     elif isinstance(obj, (ABCSeries, np.ndarray, ABCIndexClass)):
     58         return _isna_ndarraylike(obj)
```

NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: Could you please post sample data?  Based on your error, I want to take a particular look at your indices.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & include some data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/194. Why? My understanding is that plotline does'nt support multilevel dataframes.

Comment: A more complete trace on that error would be helpful as well...

Comment: Hi, I've added code that reproduces that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an edge case that causes ggplot in combination with pandas to fail.

Looking at the source code of ggplot, we find at the end of `ggploy.py: _construct_plot_data`:

```
groups = [column for _, column in discrete_aes]
if groups:
    return mappers, data.groupby(groups)
else:
    return mappers, [(0, data)]
```

So my guess is that the category is used for the groupby, which causes pandas to break.

Try casting to `object` instead of `category` and in the case of `geom_density` remove the `fill='cat'` as this causes the lines and legend to be rendered twice:

```
randCat = np.random.randint(0,2,500)
randProj = np.random.rand(1,500)
df = pd.DataFrame({'proj': np.ravel(randProj),'cat': np.ravel(randCat)})
df['cat'] = df['cat'].map({0:'firstCat', 1:'secondCat'}) 
df['cat'] = df['cat'].astype('object')

g = ggplot(aes(x='proj', color='cat'), data=df) + geom_density(alpha=0.7)
print(g)
```

See also http://ggplot.yhathq.com/how-it-works.html and http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_density.html

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

By the way, the fill aestetics doesn't work. I'll try now with different version of ggplot.

Comment: Maybe the geom_density doesn't support fill. Not sure which geom support what aes. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I overcame the "fill" issue using the seaborn package.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.kdeplot(df[df['cat'] == 'firstCat']['proj'], shade=True, label='firstCat')
sns.kdeplot(df[df['cat'] == 'secondCat']['proj'], shade=True, label='secondCat')
plt.show()
```

[Plots this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06nsJ.png)